# How to download a file from a content page inside UpdatePanel in ASP

Tags: asp.net

I want to download a file from an ASP webforms page.

If I use a WebForm without MasterPage everything is fine, I have a LinkButton with this

```
    Private Sub linkDOWNLOAD_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles linkDOWNLOAD.Click
        Dim filePath = "C:\files\" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value
        Dim fileStream As Stream = streamClient.someWebServiceReturningFileStream(filePath)
        Dim buffer(65536) As Byte
        Dim bytesRead = 0

        Response.BufferOutput = False
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment; filename=" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value)

        bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

        While (bytesRead > 0)
            If (Response.IsClientConnected) Then
                Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                Response.Flush()
                buffer = New Byte(65536) {}
                bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            Else
                bytesRead = -1
            End If
        End While

        Response.Flush()
        Response.Close()
        Response.End()
      End
```

As I said this works fine and the browser open the dialog to download the file, but if I try the same code in a button inside a content page within a MasterPage, then nothing happens.

The Master page has this UpdatePanel:

```
...
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelBODY" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="contentBODY" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>                    
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
...
```

And the content page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentBODY" runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkDOWNLOAD" runat="server">Download File</asp:LinkButton>
</asp:Content>
```

I don't know how to solve this and every example I have found is based on webforms without master page.

Thanks for your help.

SOLVED: Look the answer below.

Comment: Is your event firing? What happens when you place breakpoints?

Comment: @mxmissile yes, the event is firing, it reaches the Response.End() but don't reach the final End just finish there, I suspect this is the issue here but I don't know what to do.

Comment: `UpdatePanel` uses AJAX, I seriously doubt you can interact with the `Response` object like that to download a file. Look into the UpdatePanel triggers, might be able to work something out with those.

Comment: @mxmissile that's seems to be the problem but UpdatePanel triggers can't access controls inside the ContenPlaceHolder. Do you know any code or article I can look to perform this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

I just added another UpdatePanel with a Trigger to perform the postback inside the child page.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentBODY" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="linkDOWNLOAD" runat="server">Download
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="linkDOWNLOAD" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>    
</asp:Content>
```